# write checkmarked data to json with PHP

Tags: php, json, foreach

I have a bunch of urls I am echoing from a json file with a foreach loop. I then select some of those with a form checkbox, **which I then want to write to another json file**. But when I write to the second json file, it just grabs the last checked url, not all the checked ones.

form:

```
    <?php
    if(!empty($user_array)){
      foreach($user_array as $image){
        echo 
          <input type="checkbox" name="photo_url" value="'. $image['url'] . '">;
        }
      }
```

grab_urls.php

```
$new_json = fopen("new-order.json", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt[] = array(
  'photo_url'=> $_POST['photo_url'],
  );    
fwrite($new_json, json_encode($txt, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
fclose($new_json);
```

How can I get **all** the checked URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create multiple checkbox array.something like below:

```
<?php
if(!empty($user_array)){
  foreach($user_array as $image){
    echo 
      <input type="checkbox" name="photo_url[]" value="'. $image['url'] . '">;
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: thank you! I love it when the solution is that easy:)